# Unit test : check if a method is being called

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            save data to file
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        { 
            ErrorDisplay.ShowErrorMessage("MyMethod", exception);
        }
    }
}

public class ErrorDisplay
{
    public static ShowErrorMessage(string methodName, Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is IOException)
            MessageBox.Show(methodName + " : " + GetIODisplayMessage());
        else if ... 
            ...
        else
            ...
   }

    public static string GetIODisplayMessage()
    {
        return "IO error";
    }

    ....
}
```

I need to write a unit test in witch i will mock the IOException and i need to check that
`GetIODisplayMessage()` method is being called. Is there a way to test if a method is called?
Or maybe another idea on how to make a unit test for my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, using the static ErrorDisplay causes a number of problems with testing and injecting in an implementation of IErrorDisplay would solve some of them but not all (see MessageBox below).  However...

## Static + Interface

If you need to keep the static class ErrorDisplay and don't want to shell out for TypeMock you can add a level of indirection

```
public interface IDisplayErrorImplementation {
    void ShowErrorMessage(string message, Exception ex);
}

public class DefaultDisplayErrorImplementation : IDisplayErrorImplementation {
    public void ShowErrorMessage(string message, Exception ex) {
        //...
    }
}

public static class DisplayError {
    static DisplayError(){
        Implementation = new  DefaultDisplayErrorImplementation();
     }

    public static IDisplayErrorImplementation Implementation { get; set;}

    public static void ShowErrorMessage(string message, Exception ex) {
        Implementation.ShowErrorMessage(message, ex);
    }
}
```

You get to keep the existing calls to ErrorDisplay, but they are now more replaceable and testable.

It is not a perfect solution but, if maintaining legacy code, it lets you add some testability without having to do major rework.

## MessageBox

You have another problem with running unit tests on ErrorDisplay; you will have a MessageBox appearing. Not good if trying to run tests in a test harness (or as part of a build).

Again indirection is your friend.  You can replace the MessageBox.Show() call with a call to a MessageDisplayService.Show(). The default implementation can call message box, a dummy one can be used for testing (either a mock or simple do nothing implementation)

## Unit Testing

What are your unit boundaries for testing?

It looks from the question that you want to run a test against MyClass::MyMethod(), cause an IOException and see that GetIODisplayMessage() is invoked. If I mis-understood, please skip the next section :)

Are you planning to do this for every class/method where an IOException can occur?
Are you planning to do this for every class/method where each of the other exception types handled by ErrorDisplay can occur?

This is a lot of work to which simply re-tests the ErrorDisplay code again and again.

The boundaries I would see are

**MyClass::MyMethod**

If an Exception occurs, it calls ErrorDisplay.ShowErrorMessage() passing in "MyMethod" and the exception.

Anything after that is out of its hands and should not be part of the unit tests.

**ErrorDisplay.ShowErrorMessage()**

If it is called with an IOException then it shows the message that it gets by calling GetIODisplayMessage().

This is independent (as written above) of the calling code and can be unit tested separately.

**ErrorDisplay.GetIODisplayMessage()**

Returns the correct error message. OK, a bit of overkill if the value is hardcoded but shows the principle.

When testing MyClass::MyMethod, we want to verify that when an exception occurs, the error display code is called passing in the correct method name and exception.

When testing ErrorDisplay.ShowErrorMessage(), we verify we get the correct message for the exception type that we call the MessageDisplayService.Show() with 
    methodname + ":" + <>
we don't need to test the text of the IODisplayMessage here.

When testing ErrorDisplay.GetIODisplayMessage() we check that it returns the correct message.

Hope this is useful,

Alan.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly check if a method is being invoked, but you could extract the body in MyMethod into a separate class implementing an interface and then use some mock library like RhinoMocks to inject the behavior.

Using RhinoMock you can then instruct the mock to throw exceptions and expect invokations.

Answer (score 0):

Testing static methods is hard. You can consider changing your methods to be non-static. This is much easier if you use dependency injection. Another option is to buy a license for the commercial TypeMock library which will allow you to mock static methods by modifying the IL code. This allows you to write code that verifies that the method was called, what the arguments were, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mocking library such as Moq or Rhino Mocks
look at this [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/)

for static methods you can use [TypeMock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page-a)

but is not a free

Comment: You should avoid using static classes instead use the IoC and Dependency Injection Type Mock Isolator can work with static methods

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your mocking framework.  None of the free ones (Rhino, Moq) allow you to set expectations on static methods.  You'll need to purchase a commercial product such as Typemock or better still make the methods on the ErrorDisplay class virtual and pass an instance of this into MyClass.

As an example you can then send in an instance of `Mock<ErrorDisplay>` if using Moq and set an expectation on that.